# error C2011: 'timezone':'struct' type redefinition (postgres)

Tags: c, visual-studio, postgresql, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to build a. dll file to extend the postgres server with C functions.
I'm using visual studio 2012 to build the dll, and PostgreSQL 9.2. I imported all directories postgres "\include\server*"
But I'm having the errors:

> error C2011: 'timezone': 'struct' type redefinition
>
> error C2011: 'itimerval': 'struct' type redefinition

In the file *pg_confi_os.h* at line 205 and 214

I tried this [solution](http://exodusdb.googlecode.com/svn-history/r278/trunk/exodus/pgexodus/src/pgnaturalorder.cpp) but had no success.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: I believe few PG windows users compile from source. If you don't receive answers here I suggest you to try http://www.postgresql.org/list/pgsql-hackers/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look at this today and found that it's a bug in the PostgreSQL include files. See [this mailing list post](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/52D0F953.7030403@2ndquadrant.com).

You can work around it by explicitly defining WIN32 in your project file's preprocessor directives.

See [my blog post on the topic today](http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/compiling-postgresql-extensions-visual-studio-windows/)

Answer (score 1):

The postgresql team did answer me:

> In the first place, Note that VS2012 is not (yet) a supported build
> environment for Postgres. See
> http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/install-windows-full.html
>
> cheers

The another answer:

> First, you'll want to build with Visual Studio 2010 or older. The Express edition works fine.
>
> Second, it's very unlikely that you can just compile the extension .c file stand-alone. You'll need to set a bunch of preprocesor definitions, some of which are somewhat configuration/environment specific.
>
> The best way to compile extensions at the moment may be to get the PostgreSQL source tree, add your extension as a folder inside the contrib/ directory with a Makefile, then use the tooling in src/tools/msvc to compile the source tree including the extension.
>
> I would really like to see this improve, with a working PGXS alternative for Windows MSVC builds. I'm not presently aware of anything, but I haven't investigated building extensions out of tree under Windows/MSVC in detail yet.
>
> --
> Craig Ringer                   http://www.2ndQuadrant.com/
> PostgreSQL Development, 24x7 Support, Training & Services